# Defining variable that's a path to a file containing x string in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that would search for user defined string in files stored in certain location, I want to scan all the files in the location containing certain string, "log" in this example

```
#!/bin/bash
&fname= "/path/logfile1"*                    #1
read -p "Searching for: " pattern            #2
if [[ $fname == "log"* ]];                   #3
then                        
    result=$(grep -i "$pattern" "$fname")   
    echo "$result"                           #4
fi

1 variable consisting of a path to a directory where all the files contain string of"log" in their names
2 reading user defined pattern to be found in the above files
3 checking if file/files name/s contain/s string "log"
4 if the above met display lines containing desired string
```

Comment: @jm666, first is correct, second is not: _find /path/to/files -name '*log*' -type f -print0 | xargs grep ..._

Comment: @0andriy my bad, but the OP doesn't asked for deep-search, so the `grep patt /path/to/*log*` will be enough.

Comment: @jm666, would work